# Changing Gridview Size from Preferences when Implementing Fragments

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

I had a gridview activity where I was populating the gridview with a custom object (a picture with some custom methods and an onclick listener). I could change the gridview size from the preferences menu. Everything worked beautifully.

I have since added some complexity to the code. Instead of using the normal Activity class, I am now using the FragmentActivity class, a fragmentPageAdapter, and a fragment to which my gridview is bound. This is because eventually I want the app to allow the user "swipe" from fragment to fragment.

Since using the fragment in this way, I am noticing a repeatable bug whenever I try to resize the gridview from the preferences menu: some of the objects get resized properly, other elements do not resize. Instead, they keep the same size that they had prior to changing the preference. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Example of Image not being resized.]

This only happens when I try resizing from the preferences menu. Other calls to my resize method, such as on a configuration change, resize all of the gridview elements correctly.

I would appreciate any suggestions!

Here is my Code:

MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
package com.KhalidSorensen.animalsounds;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

    private MyFragment                  m_myFragment = new MyFragment();
    private ViewPager                   m_viewPager;
    private static SharedPreferences    m_prefs;        

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        m_prefs  = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);         
        m_prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        m_viewPager  = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        m_viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), m_myFragment));   
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        Log.i("Khalid","MainActivity: onSharedPreferenceChanged");

        if (key.equals("key_prefs_enable_lscape")){
            //do nothing for now

        }else if (key.equals("key_prefs_picture_size")){            
            SetColumnWidth(m_myFragment.getM_gridView());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.i("Khalid","FragAnimalSounds: onConfigurationChanged");

        SetColumnWidth(m_myFragment.getM_gridView());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.i("Khalid","MainActivity: onCreateOptionsMenu");

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.lbl_opt_menu_settings:
            Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.PREFERENCES");
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.lbl_opt_menu_quit:
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            finish();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void SetColumnWidth(GridView GV) {
        Log.i("Khalid","MainActivity: SetColumnWidth");

        int NumColumns,  DesiredColumnWidth;

        //Get the desired number of columns from the key prefs
        NumColumns          = Integer.parseInt(m_prefs.getString("key_prefs_picture_size","2")); 

        //Determine the desired column width
        if (NumColumns == 1){
            DesiredColumnWidth = 200;
        }else if (NumColumns == 2){
            DesiredColumnWidth = 100;
        }else{
            DesiredColumnWidth = 50;
        }

        //Set the desired column width
        GV.setColumnWidth(DesiredColumnWidth);
    }
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    Fragment m_frag_A   = null;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Fragment A) {
        super(fm);
        m_frag_A = A;   
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return m_frag_A;            //only 1 item for now
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int i) {       
        return "Title Frag A";      //only 1 item for now
    }
}
```

MY FRAGMENT (THERE IS ONLY ONE FOR NOW):

```
package com.KhalidSorensen.animalsounds;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private GridView            m_gridView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("Khalid","FragAnimalSounds: onCreateView");

        View view           = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_animal_sounds, container, false);
        m_gridView          = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.lbl_gridView);
        m_gridView.setAdapter(new VivzAdapter(view.getContext()));
        MainActivity.SetColumnWidth(m_gridView);

        return view;
    } 

    public GridView getM_gridView() {
        return m_gridView;
    }
}
```

MY GRIDVIEW ADAPTER:

```
package com.KhalidSorensen.animalsounds;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

public class VivzAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context                 m_context;
    private ArrayList<AnimalKind>   m_list = new ArrayList<AnimalKind>();
    VivzAdapter(Context ctx) {
        m_context   = ctx;  

        int[] animalphotos = { R.drawable.cat_1, R.drawable.cow_1,
                R.drawable.dog_1, R.drawable.donkey_1, R.drawable.duck_1,
                R.drawable.peacock_1, R.drawable.rooster_1, R.drawable.seal_1 };

        for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
            AnimalKind animalKind = new AnimalKind(m_context, animalphotos[i]);
            m_list.add(animalKind);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return m_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public AnimalKind getItem(int position) {
        return m_list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View v, ViewGroup vg) {
        return m_list.get(i);
    }
}
```

MY CUSTOM OBJECT CLASS. THESE OBJECTS ARE POPULATING THE GRIDVIEW:

```
package com.KhalidSorensen.animalsounds;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class AnimalKind extends ImageView  implements OnClickListener{

    private int             m_imageId;

    public AnimalKind(Context ctx, int imageId) {
        super(ctx);

        m_imageId   = imageId;

        super.setImageResource(imageId);
        super.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        super.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        super.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
        super.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        super.setOnClickListener(this);
      }


    //@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Do Something
    }

    @Override
    public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
        //Do Something
    }

    public int getM_imageId() {
        return m_imageId;
    }
}
```

MY PREFERENCE ACTIVITY:

```
package com.KhalidSorensen.animalsounds;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        Log.i("Khalid", "Preferences: onCreate");
    }
}
```

MY XML FOR MY MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_title"
        android:background="#33B5E5"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp">   "
    </android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

AND FINALLY, MY XML FOR THE GRIDVIEW:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <GridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="0px"
        android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="false"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:columnWidth="130dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:listSelector="@null"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:stretchMode="none"
        android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
    </GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CENTER_INSIDE` a scale type for your image view.

```
 super.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

another thing that I would change is the way you handle the column width. I would remove the  `android:numColumns="auto_fit"`. On the other hand you know that the number of columns is the cealing of `WidthViewGrid`/`desiderePicSize`, where the most common case for WidthViewGrid is the screen's width. On then programmatically you can set number of columns of your GridView with `setNumberOfColumns`

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

A. After calling [setColumnWidth](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2_r1/android/widget/GridView.java#GridView.setColumnWidth%28int%29) call the *gridview*.invalidate()

B. After returning from the change preference - call adapter's [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) in order to make sure it re-creates the views in the adapter (i.e. `getView` will be called)